# Setting status bar and navigation bar to be the same color

Tags: swift, statusbar, navigationbar

[image]

Hi, I wanted to set the status bar to have the exact same color as the `UINavigationBar`. I am using the exact same color in the code shown below but as you can see from the image, they are not of the same blue color.  Is there any method to get them to be the same. I tried to google but could not find any solution.

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 13/225, green: 71/255, blue:161/255, alpha: 1.0)

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 13/225, green: 71/255, blue:161/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller or did you just add a navigation bar to some view controller? With a navigation controller there is no need to try to set the color of the status bar. It will match the navigation bar of the navigation controller by default.

Comment: try this - navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

Comment: @Shezad, it works! You can post this as a solution and I will mark it as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing translucent to false

```
navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to set the status bar color if you want it to match the navbar. Commenting out the following line solves this issue in my environment.

[Screenshot of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAGhv.png)

```
// UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 13/225, green: 71/255, blue:161/255, alpha: 1.0)

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 13/225, green: 71/255, blue:161/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

Alternatively, you could do the following:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 13/225, green: 71/255, blue:161/255, alpha: 0.0)

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 13/225, green: 71/255, blue:161/255, alpha: 0.0)
```

Comment: If you managed to get the statusbar to have the exact same color as navigationbar, could you post a screenshot?  I did not manage to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blue 
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
```

I run on xcode 10.1, swift 4.2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.yourColor

Answer (score 0):

You can add below function to `AppDelegate.swift` file

```
func changeStatusBarColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        guard let statusBar = (UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBarWindow") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView else {
            return
        }
        statusBar.backgroundColor = color
    }
```

and Use in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method like below

```
self.changeStatusBarColor(UIColor.black) //pass the color you want to set
```

**Edited**

You can Use shared instance in `AppDelegate.swift` file

```
static let shared = AppDelegate()
```

After that whenever you set navigation background color just pass it to `changeStatusBarColor` method

Use below method to set same as navigation background color

```
AppDelegate.shared.changeStatusBarColor((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor)!)
```

Comment: I know how to set the color for status bar.  What I need is to get the exact same color for statusbar and the navigationbar.

Comment: @DarylWong ok i got your point, i edited my answer, please check it and let me know if it work for you or not